# Android Send and Receive Data simultaneously

Tags: android, sockets

I am trying to receive data on my android phone, from the server. I do not understand why it always crashes... Please help!

```
seekbarbrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbarbrightness, int progress, boolean b) {
            if(b==true) {
                seekbarvalue = seekbarbrightness.getProgress();
                multiplier = (double) seekbarvalue / 100;
                finallumens = (int) (multiplier * LoginActivity.enterlumens);
                tblumens.setText(String.valueOf(finallumens) + " Lumens");
                if (LoginActivity.getSocket() != null) {
                    try {



                        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(LoginActivity.getSocket().getInputStream());
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                        String str = reader.readLine();
                        tbvolts.setText("Voltage: "+str);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOT connected To Socket, please disconnect and reconnect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

If I remove the receive data codes, and place the following code in the try and catch block, it works.

```
LoginActivity.getSocket().getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf(multiplier).getBytes());
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. But below is the error I get in logcat and my app just crashes.

```
Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback.
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This is my Async Method I created. Is it correct? And any ideas how I could extract the str value in my AsyncTask and place it into a Textview? I can only Printout the value but not setting the text with it.

```
class ReceiveData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(LoginActivity.getSocket().getInputStream()));
            in.readLine();
            String str = in.readLine();
            return str;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "fail";
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I dont get it.. When i switch my code to sending out bytes, it works. But only when receiving data it doesnt..

Comment: You should not do _any_ network operation on main thread

Answer (score 0):

Long running  task puts more load on main thread that's why `NetworkOnMainThreadException`  showing, main thread is always used to perform small task like update UI etc.  To Perform long running task use AsyncTask.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/4741746

This link show you how to use  AsyncTask. in android

and after completing task if you want to update UI than  you can use `onPostExecute` method of AsyncTask

also look at this post it help you -https://stackoverflow.com/a/12650928/4741746

Comment: Another method I tried was placing the network operation into another thread, and calling thread.start() in the main thread. It works this way, but is there any practice to this?

Comment: There are multiple ways like Handler , Thread , etc but best is AsyncTask

Comment: Most of use library like retrofit , volley, loopj async library etc  in which retrofit is best

Comment: but ill suggest you to start with async task than move forward for best practice

Comment: Ahh I see. It seems my thread can only run twice, and anymore than that it will crash. May I ask for the AsyncTask, in my case, I only need to put the inputstream codes into the onPostExecute? My socket creation were created in another activity.

Comment: Yes you can use async task in this situation and put that inpute stream code in do in background method not in post execute  ....do in background  method work in background thread where as onPostExecute work on main thread   refer -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: If you don't mind, I added the AsyncTask I created. I am not very sure if it is correct. Please have a look.

Comment: Befor using Async Task please read all the details how it work - developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html